# What is the difference between Just Input and Perfect Input in Tekken 8?

Tags: tekken-8

Going through the Tekken 8 move lists of various characters, I found references to **“Just Input”** as well as **“Perfect Input”**. What exactly do these terms mean and what is the difference between them?

### Examples

**Devil Jin**’s Heat state offers the following: “Allows the use of Electric Wind God Fist without Just Input.”

**Lee**’s Heat state offers the following: “Perfect Input moves can be used without Perfect Input. Restores remaining Heat upon Perfect Input.”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to a [comment on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Tekken/comments/r5kux2/comment/kri4rk1/), the use of 2 different terms seems to be an inconsistency on the part of the translators. Both terms describe the same mechanic, i.e., having to press an input within a certain number of frames.

For example, Paul’s ff2:1 move is referred to as a “Perfect Input” but the window is quite generous.